# Load bearing wall

Tags: drywall, construction, load-bearing

Can anyone tell me if the pointed walls are load bearing wall. Is there a way to tall from the blueprint ? [image]

Comment: The wall between dining and bed 2 most likely load bearing.  The two in the bathroom(E/S) are unlikely, but might contain plumbing/electrical parts.

Comment: Been many years since I took a small lesson in blue prints, but think the circles with Xs in them for showing support/load items.  I can be mistaken.

Comment: @crip659, why do you say that? We don't even know when the home was built or whether there's a floor above, and modern roof systems don't have center bearing. Let's not throw darts in the dark, eh?

Comment: There's not enough information here to help. Please revise to tell us much more about your home.

Comment: I am mistaken.  Reading sideways I see the circles with Xs are smoke alarms.  It helps when I use my glasses.

Comment: We need to know which way the ceiling joists run. Is the roof supported by trusses?

Comment: My guess would be the bathroom walls are not, but the one above dining might be. I say might because the blueprint shows that wall a foot or so out of alignment from the rest of the walls (kitchen, leisure) running the length of the house. I'm guessing no 2nd story. Is there a basement? Can you see the joists or any supporting beams under those walls.

Comment: Its a single story and no basement either. And the home was built in 1988